# Spatial queries failing?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Spatial queries to the postgres database on a remote server are failing and giving the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT postgis_lib_version()"
PL/pgSQL function postgis_full_version() line 17 at SQL statement
```

**Is there anything I can do on my end to resolve the issue? Or can this only be resolved by the hosting company?**

Comment: Apparently PostGIS is not installed in the database you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is it possible this is a version/upgrade issue? it was previously working fine. It's clearly an issue on their end but didn't know if I could resolve it remotely.

Comment: Yes, it could be possible that either postgis or postgresql has been updated outside of a package manager and now the dependencies are no longer in sync

Comment: Could be resolved with an SSH login but then this is more sys admin work rather than developer work.

Comment: @e4c5 are you suggesting this is more appropriate in db admin or another community?

Comment: no not at all. The question does belong here.

Comment: @e4c5 We set up a vm on another hosting service until it's resolved. I should also note this error is happening on a shared server (A2). It looks like the PostGIS plugin in pgAdmin is 2.2 and when I run a query it's looking for postgis-2.0 extension files. When I use `pg_available_extensions` I can see the extension versions listed as 2.2.5. I can't create a new extension or mess with the extension files because of the shared server status and lacking permission issues but still curious what is causing pg to search for the wrong extension version?

Comment: @e4c5 due to shared hosting, we weren't able to update the extensions ourselves, (subsequently switched hosting services) which was a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how shared hosting, we weren't able to update the extensions ourselves. We subsequently switched to vps hosting which allows us to perform the maintenance ourselves.